# How to redirect input from another tty?

Tags: linux, cat, tty, procfs

When i run `cat -` in say `/dev/pts/2` and try to write to its input from another tty with `echo foo > /dev/pts/2` or `echo foo > /proc/(pid of cat)/fd/0` it just prints foo in pts/2, cat doesn't repeat it . why?
How to send input to cat from another tty so it also repeat it ?

Comment: Do you have some need to do it exactly this way? It seems a fifo could work. Here's an example of [mkfifo](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/2156).

Comment: @MicahElliott i know that using fifo it will work but just want to know why directly sending to its stdin doesn't work.

Comment: It works if input is a pipe e.g., run `cat | tr a-z A-Z` in one terminal; then `echo aBc > /proc/<pid of tr>/fd/0` in another terminal.

Comment: yes it works that way but if we `echo bar > /proc/<pid of cat>/fd/0` then after reading from its file descriptor 0 cat should write same to its file descriptor 1
which should be passed to tr though pipe and tr should write BAR to terminal. But that's not happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is a fundamental misunderstanding here: you *cannot* inject content to another TTY's input stream (unless you own the master).

You can, however, call `cat /dev/pts/0` to read from another TTY's input stream, but beware that you will be fighting whatever process is already there.

Comment: also `/dev/pts/2` is a file so when we write something to it , a program reading from it should read that.

Comment: @shanky061 Sure, a program reading from the *master* end will read it. Just like when the master writes, the slave can read.

Comment: and who is the master ?, i think cat is reading from it ?? no, then how cat reads from it , cat's fd/0 file is linked to it.

Comment: and if cat is a _slave_ then how does _slave_ get data from _master_ ?

Comment: it said : Data written to master is presented to slave as input
and for a corresponding slave file there should be master file but i have 3 slave file and 1 master file in pts directory and when i try to write to master file with root permissions it does nothing..

Comment: @shanky061 Anything you're doing is a slave only.

Answer (score 1):

Each and every terminal has a file for it, in /dev/pts/.

> $ ps

to determine which terminal you are on. Example: I am on terminal 3

> PID     TTY     TIME CMD
>
> 1477  pts/3    00:00:00 ps
>
> 26511 pts/3    00:00:01 bash

Than just redirect your output to that terminal.

> cat foo > /dev/pts/3

<s>Make a first in first out pipe on the second terminal, the one you'd like to display the text on</s>

```
mkfifo --mode=600 /tmp/pipe
```

Redirect the command to that pipe on the first terminal

```
cat foo > /tmp/pipe
```

Comment: cat doesn't repeating the data received from another tty using your method, also don't give me fifo solutions.

Comment: Or run `tty` to see your own TTY name.

Comment: Sorry it didn't help. Wish you luck!
@o11c I did not know that. Great to know!